# Understanding O(1) vs O(n) Time Complexity Intuitively

Tags: arrays, algorithm, memory, time-complexity

I understand that O(1) is constant-time, which means that the operation does not depend on the input size, and O(n) is linear time, which means that the operation changes linearly with input size.

If I had an algorithm that could simply go directly to an array index rather than going through each index one-by-one to find the required one, that would be considered constant-time rather than linear-time, right? This is what the textbooks say. But, intuitively, I don't understand how a computer could work this way: Wouldn't the computer still need to go through each index one-by-one, from 0 to (potentially) n, in order to find the specific index given to it? But then, is this not the same as what a linear-time algorithm does?

### Edit

My response to ElKamina's answer elaborates on how my confusion extends to hardware:

> But wouldn't the computer have to check where it is on its journey to
> the index? For instance, if it's trying to find index 3, "I'm at index
> 0 so I need address 0 + 3", "Ok, now I'm at address 1, so I have to
> move forward 2", "Ok, now I'm at address 2, so I have to move forward
> 1", "Ok, now I'm at index 3". Isn't those the same thing as what
> linear-time algorithms do? How can the computer not do it
> sequentially?

Comment: This actually seems like more of a hardware or general software question, as it comes down to explaining how memory works. I'd be inclined to point you to [su], but you'd likely have to rewrite the question first, and you can probably find a decent explanation of RAM if you Google it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Theory**

Imagine you have an array which stores events in the order they happened. If each event takes the same amount of space in a computer's memory, you know where that array begins, and you know what number event you're interested in, then you can precalculate the location of each event.

Imagine you want to store records and key them by telephone numbers. Since there are many numbers, you can calculate a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of each one. The simplest hash you might apply is to treat the telephone number like a regular number and take it modulus the length of the array you'd like to store the number in. Again, you can assume each record takes the same amount of space, you know the number of records, you know where the array begins, and you know the offset of the event of interest. From these, you can precalculate the location of each event.

If array items have different sizes, then instead fill the array with pointers to the actual items. Your lookup then has two stages: find the appropriate array element and then follow it to the item in question.

Much like we can use shmancy GPS systems to tell us where an address is, but we still need to do the work of driving there, the problem with accessing memory is not knowing where an item is, it's getting there.

**Answer to your question**

With this in mind, the answer to your question is that look-up is almost never free, but it also is rarely *O(N)*.

**Tape memory: *O(N)***

[image: Magnetic tape]

[Tape memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive) requires *O(N)* seeks, for obvious reasons: you have to spool and unspool the tape to position it to the needed location. It's slow. It's also cheap and reliable, so it's still in use today in long-term back-up systems. [Special algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Use_with_tape_drives) which account for the physical nature of the tape can speed up operations on it slightly.

Notice that, per the foregoing, the problem with tape is not that we don't  know where the thing is we're trying to find. The problem is getting the physical medium to get there. The nature of a good tape algorithm is to try to minimize the total amount of tape spooled and unspooled over a grouping of operations.

Speaking of which, what if, instead of having one long tape, we had two shorter tapes: this would reduce the point-to-point travel time. What if we had four tapes?

**Disk memory: *O(N)*, but smaller**

Hard drives make a huge reduction in seek time by turning the tape into a series of rings. Now, even though there are *N* memory spaces on a disk, any one can be accessed in short order by moving the drive head and the disk to the appropriate point. (Figuring out how to express this in big-oh notation is a challenge.)

[image: Hard disk image]

Again, if you use faster disks or smaller disks, you can [optimize performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics#Short_stroking).

**RAM: O(1), but with caveats**

Pretty much everyone who answers this question is going to fixate on RAM, since that's what programmers work with most frequently. Look to their answers for fuller explanations.

But, just briefly, RAM is a natural extension of the ideas developed above. The RAM holds *N* items and we know where the item we want is. However, this time there's nothing that needs to mechanically move in order for us to get to that item. In addition, we saw that by having more short tapes or smaller, faster drives, we could get to the memory we wanted faster. RAM takes this idea to its extreme.

For practical purposes, you can think of RAM as being a collection of little memory stores, all strung together. Your computer doesn't know exactly where in RAM a particular item is, just the collection it belongs to. So it grabs the whole collection, consisting of thousands or millions of bytes. It stashes this in something like an L3 cache.

But where is a particular item in that cache? Again, you can think of the computer as not really knowing, it just grabs the a subset which is guaranteed to include the item and passes it to the L2 cache.

And again, for the L1 cache.

And, at this point, we've gone from gigabytes (or terabytes) of RAM to something like 3-30 kilobytes. And, at this level, your computer (finally) knows exactly where the item is and grabs it for processing.

This kind of hierarchical behavior means that accessing adjacent items in RAM is much faster than randomly accessing different points all across RAM. That was also true of tape drives and hard disks.

However, *unlike* tape drives and hard disks, the worst-case time where all the caches are missed is not dependent on the amount of memory (or, at least, is very weakly dependent: path lengths, speed of light, &c)! For this reason, you can treat it as an *O(1)* operation in the size of the memory.

**Comparing speeds**

Knowing this, we can talk about access speed by looking at [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832):

[image: Latency numbers]

```
Latency Comparison Numbers
--------------------------
L1 cache reference                           0.5 ns
Branch mispredict                            5   ns
L2 cache reference                           7   ns                      14x L1 cache
Mutex lock/unlock                           25   ns
Main memory reference                      100   ns                      20x L2 cache, 200x L1 cache
Compress 1K bytes with Zippy             3,000   ns        3 us
Send 1K bytes over 1 Gbps network       10,000   ns       10 us
Read 4K randomly from SSD*             150,000   ns      150 us          ~1GB/sec SSD
Read 1 MB sequentially from memory     250,000   ns      250 us
Round trip within same datacenter      500,000   ns      500 us
Read 1 MB sequentially from SSD*     1,000,000   ns    1,000 us    1 ms  ~1GB/sec SSD, 4X memory
Disk seek                           10,000,000   ns   10,000 us   10 ms  20x datacenter roundtrip
Read 1 MB sequentially from disk    20,000,000   ns   20,000 us   20 ms  80x memory, 20X SSD
Send packet CA->Netherlands->CA    150,000,000   ns  150,000 us  150 ms
```

In more human terms, these look like:

```
Minute:

L1 cache reference                  0.5 s         One heart beat (0.5 s)
Branch mispredict                   5 s           Yawn
L2 cache reference                  7 s           Long yawn
Mutex lock/unlock                   25 s          Making a coffee

Hour:

Main memory reference               100 s         Brushing your teeth
Compress 1K bytes with Zippy        50 min        One episode of a TV show (including ad breaks)

Day:

Send 2K bytes over 1 Gbps network   5.5 hr        From lunch to end of work day

Week:

SSD random read                     1.7 days      A normal weekend
Read 1 MB sequentially from memory  2.9 days      A long weekend
Round trip within same datacenter   5.8 days      A medium vacation
Read 1 MB sequentially from SSD    11.6 days      Waiting for almost 2 weeks for a delivery

Year:

Disk seek                           16.5 weeks    A semester in university
Read 1 MB sequentially from disk    7.8 months    Almost producing a new human being
The above 2 together                1 year

Decade:

Send packet CA->Netherlands->CA     4.8 years     Average time it takes to complete a bachelor's degree
```

Comment: But the point with RAM is, since there's a worst case time for missing all caches that doesn't depend at all on the distance between the addresses, that access in total can be considered O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Underlying any calculation of time complexity is a cost model.  Cost models tend to be oversimplified; for example, we generally talk about the time complexity of sort algorithms in terms of how many elements do we have to compare to each other.

The assumption underlying concluding that indexing into an array is *O(1)* is that of *random access memory*; that we can access location *N* by encoding *N* on the address lines of the memory bus, and the contents of that location come back on the data bus.  If memory were *sequential access* (e.g., accessing off of a magnetic tape), we'd assume a different cost model.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that the memory is "Random Access Memory" (also known as RAM), not the tape or disk memory. In RAM you can access any address in constant time. See the corresponding wiki article for more information on how it works.

Also, elements of the array are stored sequentially. Say we want to store integers in Java which take up 4 bytes. If we wanted to look for kth element, we would directly look at `start + 4 * k` location in the memory.

You could implement an array in other ways as well. For example, you could implement the array with a linked list, in which case it would take O(n) time to access an element. But this is not how arrays are implemented typically.

Comment: But wouldn't the computer have to check where it is on its journey to the index? For instance, if it's trying to find index 3, "I'm at index 0 so I need address 0 + 3", "Ok, now I'm at address 1, so I have to move forward 2", "Ok, now I'm at address 2, so I have to move forward 1", "Ok, now I'm at index 3". Isn't those the same thing as what linear-time algorithms do? How can the computer not do it sequentially?

Comment: @ThePointer No. Read and try to understand how random access memory (RAM) works. I recommend starting with the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine computer memory as buckets, say you have 10 buckets in from of you.
if someone tells you to pick something up from bucket number 8, you will not first stick your hand into bucket 1 to 7. you would simply put your hand directly into bucket 8.

Arrays work the same way, in most languages map to some form of memory layout. so e.g. if you have an byte array of 10 that would be 10 sequential bytes.
other types could vary in size depending if the content is a value type/struct or if it is a reference type where the array would consist of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

No one here has explained **why** (IMO) in sufficient detail you can access it in O(1) time in detail, so I will try to:

As a note before I do, this is probably trivializing how complex the hardware in the computer has become, but hopefully it's something along the right path. You would cover this in a Computer Organization course that goes into the guts of the hardware.

When you have circuits, the voltage passed through the computer propagates very fast, and the results that come back depends on the pulse of the clock. Take this diagram for example:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Square_array_of_mosfet_cells_read.png

The following is missing parts that you would learn properly from a textbook or course (or online), but omission of those details should still leave you with sufficient enough of a high level overview for a rough idea of how this works:

The address you send as bits will go up the left side of the image, and based on the address size you send, the voltage will be properly sent to the proper memory cell that has the data you want. Upon the cell receiving voltage, it will then emit the value back down to the bottom (which also is basically instant), and now you've read the 'value stored in memory' since the data you want has arrived. Because of how fast voltage travels, you pretty much almost instantly get the result due to the speed of voltage change in circuits. This means *it does not depend on traversing the elements before it* since you can just go to it, which is the idea behind RAM. The bottleneck comes from the clock pulse with the latches, which when you take a computer organization course you will see what we do and why we do it.

This is why we consider it doable in O(1) time.

Now an Operating Systems and Computer Organization course would show you all about how this is connected under the hood, why its *way more complex* than what I've written (and what might not even be that accurate anymore), but hopefully gives you an intuition as to why we can do it in constant time.

Since complexity notation hides the constants under the hood (which from the above, we can assume it's constant time to go to any offset in memory), it then would make sense that we can jump to any array offset in O(1) time from a high level point of view -- which is what complexity analysis aims to do for us -- compared to. This is also why we don't need to traverse over every element in memory to get where we want, which as you said is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data structure you are talking about is a vector/array, you can easily reach index 'x' by incrementing whatever you use to iterate over it.

Say you have a vector of struct "A" where A occupies 20bytes, say you want to get to index 28 and you know the vector starts at memory location 'x', than you simply need to go to x + 20 bytes and that is your element.

With a data structure like a list the lookup time will be O(n) since its not continously assigned you have to jump from pointer to pointer.

With a binary tree its O(log2(n)) ... etc

So the answer here is that it depend on your structure. I would recommend reading some books about fundamental data structures, those might help you greatly in gaining more theoretical understanding of the various concepts you are using.